# Git failed to check out font file

Tags: git

I was trying to clone a web application project to my windows 7.

However I got some error messages:

```
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Blk.otf (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Hv.otf (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.otf (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file assets/cashback/fonts/Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Th.otf (No such file or directory)
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

This works fine when I cloned it from a Linux machine. Even I downloaded and installed the font, this is still happening. I am using TortoiseGit 1.8.12.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Is there any special char in the file name originally? Is there case-sensitive naming expected? Because Linux and Windows do similar approach to file system but with few differences.

Comment: The mixture of slashes and backslashes is suspicious. It may be trying to create `Helvetica Neue LT Std\HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf` as a filename, which unix can do but Windows can't.

Comment: Definately the backslashes. Just tried that in a test repo on a linux box and windows git produces the same message that it cannot create "a\b.txt" for me.

Comment: ahh.. yep.. I did not see that and thought it was related the font somehow...thanks for pointing that out.